# How to connect button to preexisting jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="message">
     <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="send_message" placeholder="Enter text ..."></textarea>
     <a href="#message" class="btn btn-large btn-info"  data-toggle="tab">OK</a>
     <a href="#message" class="btn btn-large btn-info"  data-toggle="tab">Cancel</a>
```

I have some pre-existing jquery code that I am trying to link the button, so that depending what the caption of the button is a unique action will occur:

```
$(function(){
   $('a.btn').click(function(){

        if( $(this).is(":contains(Cancel)") ) {
            console.log("im in Cancel!!");
            $("#send_message").val("");
        }
        else if( $(this).is(":contains(OK)") )  {
               ...............
```

right now when the button is clicked I get :

```
  http://localhost/myproject/#message
```

when I log 'this' to the console.

What should I do to connect the button click action to the if - elseif code?

Comment: Why not use data tag i.e. data-action="Ok" data-action="Cancel" and then check on that?

Comment: I'm not clear on what the problem is. Is the click event firing for your links? If so, then where is the issue? Can you reproduce the problem with a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the data attributes for mentioning the action and check it on click.
HTML:

```
 <a href="#message" class="btn btn-large btn-info"  data-toggle="tab" data-action="ok">OK</a>
 <a href="#message" class="btn btn-large btn-info"  data-toggle="tab" data-action="cancel">Cancel</a>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
  $('a.btn').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
    var action = $(this).data("action");
    switch(action)
   {

     case "ok":
       alert('Okay action');
       break;
     case "cancel":
       alert('Cancel action');
       break;
   }
 });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm sorry , obviously I'm not knowledgeable about jquery/javascript, but what is the advantage of data attributes in this case? - Bill

Comment: In this case it's just to avoid use of use jquery contains function, it's much more cleaner way to get extra info on button which is clicked.

Comment: BTW, you problem is not clear. Everybody is guessing. May be you can clarify a bit.

Comment: One last question, I notice you put "e.preventDefault()" in your code, and I think now understand that in this case the action "http://localhost/myproject/#message " is the default action. how do you know in advance what the default action is ( I hope this is not a dumb question ) ?

Comment: preventDefault simply means that default action of the event will not be triggered.  For example, if you had anchor url with the #message (#message is not going to server, it for client) is supposed to be the default action on anchor that will go to server but preventDefault() has stopped it from going to server, hence you decide inside the click event handler what you want to do. hope this is clear. here you do not have any url but only hash, so actually you don't need to preventDefault in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [**event.preventDefault()**](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

> If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.

Use

```
 $('a.btn').click(function(event){
     event.preventDefault(); //To stop default action
     //Rest of code
 });
```

Additionally, You should use `data-*` to store addition information

HTML

```
 <a href="#message" class="btn btn-large btn-info" data-action="OK" data-toggle="tab">OK</a>
```

To use it

```
  $('a.btn').click(function(event){
     event.preventDefault(); //To stop default action
     //Rest of code
     var action = $(this).data('action');
  });
```

Comment: Just for my own info Satpal, the default action here is to going to "http://localhost/myproject/#message " ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).on("ready", function(){
    $("a.btn").on("click", function(){
        if($(this).text() == "OK")
        {
            console.log("Ok")
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("Cancel");
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: While this answer may be correct. It does not look obvious what the OP is asking. Also note it's a good idea to explain your code and show why it solves the problem.